# how to replace text with another like to mail merge?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin

I am working in Magento, and i have developed a module to send text messages to customers. In the settings of the module, the admin can set the message that will be sent to the customer. I'm trying to add a features that will allow the replacement of texts with data from my database.

for example, i currently have the following code that fetches the saved settings for the body of the text message:

```
$body = $settings['sms_notification_message'];
```

The message that is fetched looks like this:

```
Dear {{firstname}},

your order ({{ordernumber}}) has been shipped.
tracking#: {(trackingnumber}}

Thanks for your business!
{{storename}}
```

The goal is to have the module replace the variables in "{{ }}" with the customer and store information.
Unfortunately, i'm unable to figure out how to make it replace the information before sending the message. It is currently being send as is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hate to say that you're reinventing the wheel without having seen your module, but it sure sounds like it.

The transactional email system in Magento does exactly this. With it you could do as you describe:

```
{{var order.increment_id}}

{{customvar code="storename"}}
```

---

Source:

http://www.srikanth.me/magento-customizing-email-templates/

Comment: well as stated in the question, this is for my module which has nothing to do with emails. I actually didn't think about looking at the email template code to see how it works and copy it. i figured out how to get it done tho. Regardless thanks for the  info.

Comment: Yeah I would have suggested not recreating a transactional system and instead *utilizing* the existing transactional email system. This allows you to have translation, variable interpolation, some logic via {{if}} and injecting other blocks and static blocks. But, either way if you get the job done!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, see code bellow.

```
// Set up the message
$tmessage = $settings['sms_notification_message'];

// Assign the values in an associative array
$values = [
    'firstname' => 'firstnamevalue',
    'ordernumber' => 'ordernumbervalue',
    'trackingnumber' => 'trackingnumbervalue',
    'storename' => 'storenamevalue'
];

// Create arrays $target indicating the value to change
$targets = [];
foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
    $targets[] = '{{'.$k.'}}';
}

// Use str_replace to perform the substitution
$body = str_replace($targets,$values,$tmessage);
```

Comment: If this answered your question please accept the answer